# Linked List, remove element by returning a new list

Tags: java, linked-list, iterator

Using Java, I have a linked LList class and a LLNode class. I am trying to remove an element from my Linked List, by returning a new linked list without the element. Basically if the list does not contain the specific element then return it,  but if it does create a new one. I iterate through my current list to see if it contains the element e, not exactly sure how to create a list without that specific element.

```
public LList<T> remove(T t) {
   if (this.contains(t)) {
      LList<T> newList = new LLSet<>(this.head);
        newList.head = new LLNode<>(, this.head);

        return newList;
      }

        return this;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming LList and LLNodes are your own classes.
My first question is why do you wish to return new list if you can remove element from same list and return it? What you should do is,
Since linked list has nodes linked, probably you should 
 1. Traverse the list one by one 
 2. and remove the element passed in the method.

But if you really wish to achieve this by returning new list. Below is what you have to do,
 1. Create a new list
 2. Iterate over older list and fill the new list with elements from old list
 3. Skip the element that you want to remove in the loop

My suggestion, don't create new list but modify existing. That's the benefit of having LinkedList.

Answer (score 0):

You have to construct a new list with new nodes. If you try to share the nodes, you will make the changes to both lists.

I think a simple `while` loop can be used to create the new list:

```
public LList<T> remove(T t) {
    LList<T> newList = new LList<>();
    LLNode<T> current = this.head;
    while (current != null) {
        if (!current.element.equals(t)) {
            newList.add(t)
        }
    }
    return newList;
}
```

If this is actually the functionality you want, and you have the liberty to change the method name, I would recommend calling it `without(T t)`. Most people would expect `remove(T t)` to modify the list it was called on.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your remove method is in the LList class. Try this:

```
public LList<T> remove(T t) {

   LLNode curr = this.head;
   LLNode prev = null;

   while(curr != null) {

        if (curr.equals(T)) {
           prev.setNext(curr.next());
           return this.head;
        }

        prev = curr;
        curr = curr.next();
   }

   return this.head;
}
```